# Python Paramiko script for Tor proxy ssh

Tags: python, ssh, proxy, paramiko, tor

I realize a proxy ssh connection using a Python script with Paramiko module with this simple code:

```
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
proxy_cmd = "connect -R remote -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p"
proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(proxy_cmd)
ssh.connect(iptarget, username=user, password=p, sock=proxy)
```

Now I would perform different attempts to the same iptarget with different username. I add to the previous code a for in order to do ssh connection for a list of user, i.e. :

```
listUser=["bob", "user", "1234"]
for user in listUser:
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  proxy_cmd = "connect -R remote -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p"
  proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(proxy_cmd)
  ssh.connect(iptarget, username=user, password=p, sock=proxy)
  time.sleep(50)
```

but I get into the following exception:

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2000, in _check_banner
buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 353, in readline
buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 546, in _read_timeout
raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1854, in run
self._check_banner()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2005, in _check_banner
'Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Exception: ('connect -R remote -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p', 'Broken pipe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 66, in send
self.process.stdin.write(content)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1852, in run
self.packetizer.write_all(b(self.local_version + '\r\n'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 309, in write_all
n = self.__socket.send(out)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 72, in send
raise ProxyCommandFailure(' '.join(self.cmd), e.strerror)
paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure: ('connect -R remote -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p', 'Broken pipe')
```

I think because I launch many connect, located in proxy command, but I do not know how to fix the problem.

I update the code, and it is work:

```
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  proxy_cmd = "connect -R remote -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 'targetip' 22"
  proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(proxy_cmd)
  ssh.connect(iptarget, username=user, password=p, sock=proxy)
```

But it still does not work in a for loop:

```
listUser=["bob", "user", "1234"]
for user in listUser:
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  proxy_cmd = "connect -R remote -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9050 192.1.1.1 22"
  proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(proxy_cmd)
  ssh.connect(iptarget, username=user, password=p, sock=proxy)
  time.sleep(50)
```

In this case I obtain these errors:

```
Exception: ('connect -R remote -4 -S 127.0.0.1:9150 192.1.1.1 22', 'Broken pipe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 66, in send
self.process.stdin.write(content)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1852, in run
self.packetizer.write_all(b(self.local_version + '\r\n'))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 309, in write_all
n = self.__socket.send(out)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/proxy.py", line 72, in send
raise ProxyCommandFailure(' '.join(self.cmd), e.strerror)
paramiko.ssh_exception.ProxyCommandFailure: ('connect -R remote -4 -S 127.0.0.1:9150 192.1.1.1 22', 'Broken pipe')
```

Comment: With 'targetip' I mean for example 192.1.1.1. I update it in the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **banner_timeout** to avoid this issue.

```
ssh.connect(iptarget, username=user, password=p, sock=proxy, banner_timeout=120)
```